# Execute jquery ajax function after PHP POST

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, post, mobile

I am creating a mobile app, using jQuery Mobile and Ajax calls to PHP.
I have several mobile pages defined in the same php-file that lets the user filter down on location, type of item etc using listviews. 
On some of my PHP pages I am using forms in panels to add new records.
Everything works fine except I can't figure out how to get back to the same page with the same selections, after I have added a record with a form POST?
In the normal selection workflow I use a Ajax call to populate the page in question with the correctly filtered data, based on the previous page, but to do that I would have to execute the jQuery Ajax function in my page when the page is created with PHP.
To do that the only way I have come up with is to use the PHP header function and submit the search parameters in the URL and then catch these when the web page is created and dynamically create some type of javascript onload event that executes the Ajax function with the parameters I have submitted, but surely there must be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the way that I solved this in the end was to do all the form POSTS with Ajax calls, then I could reload the same page through javascript on complete, rather than trying to reload the page from PHP somehow.